# Vertical spacing problem with align and split environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, split, vertical-spacing

I'm having a vertical spacing problem when I show four equations, in two columns.  This MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \nabla \cdot \vec{E} &= 0,
    &\nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\: \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, \\
    \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0,
    &\nabla \times \vec{B} &= +\: \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
\end{align}
Blablabla bla bla blabla:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    \nabla \cdot \vec{E} &= 0, \\
    \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0,
\end{split}
&
\begin{split}
    \nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\: \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, \\
    \nabla \times \vec{B} &= +\: \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The first set of equations is perfect, but I need a single tag number for the whole set, instead of two tag numbers.  So I used the split environment for a second set of identical equations.

Preview with the problem shown in red:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I make the vertical spacing exactly the same for the two columns?  Is there a way to do this without adding a `\vphantom` part?

The winner wins a cookie.

Comment: The `\:` commands should be removed.

Comment: @egreg, why?  Without them, there's not enough space between - and the fraction.

Comment: Which is the normally used way.

Comment: @egreg, well I always found this very ugly, and not clear enough.  I believe there should be a bit more space there, so that's why I use \:.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \nabla \cdot \vec{E} &= 0,
    &\nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\: \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, \\
    \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0,
    &\nabla \times \vec{B} &= +\: \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
\end{align}

Blablabla bla bla blabla:
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    \nabla \cdot \vec{E} &= 0,\qquad&\nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\: \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, \\[\jot]
    \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0,&\nabla \times \vec{B} &= +\: \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, now the horizontal spacing is too small.

Comment: @Cham, instead of `qquad` use `\hspace{5em}` ...

Comment: @Zarko or 100cm is even bigger

Comment: Why use `alignedat`?  Why not just `aligned`?